# how to load html file with ajax javascript

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I made some input forms with html.erb file. (location: addform/_form.html.erb)
and I want to call this input form in other html.erb pages (location: main/_form.html.erb).
[image]

I'd like to add additional form(addform/_form.html.erb file) when I click + button and also save in db.

How can I load `html.erb` file with ajax script? The code below doesn't work:
(ajax and controller)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#demo").click(function(){
            $("#result").load("addform/_form.html.erb");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i want to add more form everytime when i click + button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe in main/_form.html.erb

```
= render "addform/_form.html.erb"
```

Hide it with jquery.hide() or css display:none by default. And show this form in click event.